# Finding the value of a constant given a probability density function

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

So we're given the following information:

Let X be a random variable with probability density function:

$f(x)=c(1-x^2)$ if $-1<x<1$ 
$f(x)=0 $ otherwise

Find the value of c

How do I work this out?

Comment: Hint:  the total probability (aka area under the curve) has to be $1$.

Comment: Sooo...take the definite integral at -1 and 1 and set the evaluated value equal to 1 and solve for c?

Comment: that is exactly right.